# Intersection of Neighborhoods

Tags: real-analysis

If $x$ is not equal to $y$, show that there are neighborhoods $U$ of $x$ and $V$ of $y$ such that $U \cap V$ is equal to the null set.

I started my proof with: Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x$ and $V$ be a neighborhood of $y$. Assume $x$ does not equal $y$. Thus, $U$ does not equal $V$.
I'm not sure how to proceed.

We are assuming this is a metric space.

Comment: This is not true for general topological spaces. So which space are you talking about?

Comment: The start of your proof is wrong $U$ can be neighborhood of $x$ and $y$ in spite of $x\neq y$, So $U$ and $V$ can coincide.

Comment: I'm not sure @Stefan The definition of a neighborhood that I'm using is that the set U is a neighborhood of c if there exists epsilon>0 so that U contains the epsilon neighborhood of c.

Comment: @drhab How should I start then?

Comment: @britgirl5 Well, seems like you are talking about a metric space then. This is highly relevant, because your claim holds for those kind of topological spaces.

Comment: The whole space *is* a neighborhood of $x$ as well as of $y$, so it is obvious that  a "neighborhood of x" is not an exclusive property of x but may contain other points fro which it is a neighborhood, too.

Comment: First of all add information about the space to your question. As said in the comments this statement is not true for every topological space.

Comment: For the trivial topology (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology), your statement is wrong. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom

Comment: Now realize that $d(x,y)>0$. Let e.g. $r=\frac13d(x,y)$ and have a look at the open balls $B(x,r)$ and $B(y,r)$. They are neighborhoods of $x,y$  respectively and can be shown to be disjoint.

Answer (score 3):

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, where $X$ is the underlying set and $d \colon X \times X \to \mathbb R$ is the metric. (For example $X = \mathbb R$ and $d(x,y) = \|x - y\|$). Given $x, y \in X$ with $x \neq y$ we have that $d(x,y) > 0$. Let $\epsilon = \frac{d(x,y)}{2}$ and let $U = B_\epsilon (x)$ and $V = B_\epsilon(y)$ be the $\epsilon$-Balls with radius $\epsilon$ around $x$ (repectively $y$). These are neighborhoods of $x$ (respectively $y$) and thus we only have to check that $U \cap V = \emptyset$.

Fix $u \in U$. Then $d(x,u) < \epsilon$. In order to see that $u \not \in V$ it suffices to show that $d(y,u) > \epsilon$. By the triangle inequality we have $2 \epsilon = d(x,y) \le d(x,u) + d(y,u) < \epsilon + d(y,u)$ and thus $d(y,u) > \epsilon$. Thus $u \not \in V$ As $u \in U$ was arbitrary, this yields $U \cap V = \emptyset$ as desired.